# If statement in variable

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

I've seen many posts with problems like this but i couldn't find a right answer that worked out.
The problem is that i have a code that says if ... is empty, make variable ... (see code below).
This variable is a form and in this form you have things like name, message etc. What i want is the placeholder of the name, if user is logged in to be his name, which is saved in my database. This is the code:

```
    $action = isset($_POST["action"]) ? $_POST["action"] : "";
if (empty($action)) { 
    // Send back the contact form HTML
    $output = "<div style='display:none'>
    <div class='contact-top'></div>
    <div class='contact-content'>
        <h1 class='contact-title'>Stuur een bericht voor hulp:</h1>
        <div class='contact-loading' style='display:none'></div>
        <div class='contact-message' style='display:none'></div>
        <br><br><form action='#' style='display:none'>
            <input type='text' id='contact-name' class='contact-input' name='name' tabindex='1001' placeholder='Naam*' /><br><br>
            <input type='text' id='contact-email' class='contact-input' name='email' tabindex='1002' placeholder='Email*' /><br><br>";
```

And this is what i want but what doesn't work:

```
<input type='text' id='contact-name' class='contact-input' name='name' tabindex='1001' placeholder=', " if (logged_in() === true) {echo $user_data["name"] } else { echo 'Naam'; } " ,' /><br><br>
```

Hope someone can help, thanks in advance,

Paul

(naam = name in my language)

Comment: You shoule add `<?php ?>` at your input

Comment: @LLL I think he rather tries to do it inside string containing html, and not in template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to surround your if in `<?php` tags

```
 <input type='text' id='contact-name' class='contact-input' name='name' tabindex='1001' placeholder="<?php  if (logged_in() === true) { echo $user_data["name"]; } else { echo 'Naam'; } ?>" /><br><br>
```

**PS** Conditions are not working inside strings, so if you need it outside of the html template, you need do it before the string:

```
$name = 'Naam';
if (logged_in() === true) { $name = $user_data["name"]; }    

$html = "<input type='text' id='contact-name' class='contact-input' name='name' tabindex='1001' placeholder="{$name}" /><br><br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this at the top of your file

```
 <?php if(logged_in()==true){ $name = $user_data["name"];} else {$name="Naam*";};?>
```

Then echo $name in the form...

```
<input type='text' id='contact-name' class='contact-input' name='name' tabindex='1001' placeholder='<?php echo $name;?>' /><br><br>
```

Its a little more seperated and cleaner like that

Basically like this...

```
  $action = isset($_POST["action"]) ? $_POST["action"] : "";
  if (empty($action)) { 
  if(logged_in()==true){ $name = $user_data["name"];} else {$name="Naam*";};
  // Send back the contact form HTML
   $output = "<div style='display:none'>
   <div class='contact-top'></div>
   <div class='contact-content'>
    <h1 class='contact-title'>Stuur een bericht voor hulp:</h1>
    <div class='contact-loading' style='display:none'></div>
    <div class='contact-message' style='display:none'></div>
    <br><br><form action='#' style='display:none'>
        <input type='text' id='contact-name' class='contact-input' name='".$name."' tabindex='1001' placeholder='Naam*' /><br><br>
        <input type='text' id='contact-email' class='contact-input' name='email' tabindex='1002' placeholder='Email*' /><br><br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to concatenate the variable you want to put in your string. For example, you can do :

```
if (User is logged)
    naam = 'USERNAME';
else
    naam = '';
```

and in your output :

```
<input type='text' id='contact-name' class='contact-input' name='name' tabindex='1001' placeholder='".$naam."' />
```